# CToolTipCtrl question

Tags: mfc

I use CToolTipCtrl component in my application and it works fine. But also I need in additional setting: tooltips should appear only after 10 seconds from moment when mouse are on button.

Does this component have any property like setShowTime() or some function can be called to setup waiting period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the delay time just calling [SetDelayTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e60zs4d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You just need to check msdn it's not that hard.